# How to create an array of C-strings?

Tags: c++, arrays, c-strings

So I would just like to create an array of C-strings in C++. Yes, I know that C++ uses the string data type, but what I'm working on requires me to make an array of C-strings. C-strings themselves are an array of chars. So would making an array of C-strings be just like making a two-dimensional char array? And then to access each individual char I would need to specify its respective row and column position. However, I would like to imagine this as a single-dimensional array of C-strings, where every index returns a complete C-string. How can I do that? Please explain. How do I loop through such an array and print out or return every C-string instead of having nested loops to return every char separately?

Answer (score 4):

For string literals you can just do this:

```
const char *strings[] = { "foo", "bar", "blech" };
```

For an array of strings you want to modify you might do something more like this:

```
char strings[3][80] = { "foo", "bar", "blech" };
```

Either way you can just print them like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    std::cout << strings[i] << std::endl;
}
```

or perhaps more idiomatically:

```
for (auto & s : strings)
{
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A C-style string is nothing more than, basically, an *array* of `char`, terminated with a `'\0'`. To have an array of "strings" you simply have an array of arrays, like

```
char my_array_of_strings[ARRAY_SIZE][STRING_SIZE + 1];  // +1 for terminator
```

*Or* you could have an array of pointers:

```
char* my_array_of_strings[ARRAY_SIZE];
```

Which one is best depends on your use-cases.